# device-detector library doesn't work in php

Tags: php, device, user-agent

I'm trying to figure out what users device model so my application allow them only with thier own registered device and I found this device-detector library(https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector). My server do not use composer and php version is 5.3 . However when I try to use it it returns nothing and I have no clue. can someon help me with this? code is below

```
  <?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once '../lib/Mobile_Detect.php';  //another library

 include_once __DIR__ . '/spyc/Spyc.php'; //to use device-detector without composer
 include_once __DIR__ . '/device-detector/autoload.php'; 
//  include_once __DIR__ . '/device-detector/DeviceDetector.php'; 

        
use DeviceDetector\ClientHints;
use DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector;
use DeviceDetector\Parser\Device\AbstractDeviceParser;

$detect = new Mobile_Detect;  
//1 is mobile,2 is pc
$devicetype = $detect->isMobile() ? 1 : 2;   

//when it is mobile
if($devicetype == 1){ 
    $devicemake = "";     
    foreach($detect->getRules() as $name => $regex){ 
        if(substr($name, -2) == "OS") break;      
        $check = $detect->{'is'.$name}(); 
        if($check) { 
             $devicemake = str_replace("Tablet","",$name);   //Tablet
             break; 
        } 
     }

    //device OS
     $deviceos = $detect->isiOS() ? "iOS" : ($detect->isAndroidOS() ? "Android" : "ETC"); 
     if($deviceos == "iOS"){ 
         $deviceosv = $detect->version("iOS");    //OS version(iOS)
     } else if ($deviceos == "Android"){ 
         $deviceosv = $detect->version("Android");  //OS info(Android)
     } else { 
         $deviceosv = $detect->version("Mobile");   //OS info(ETC)
     } 

     echo "factory : ".$devicemake."<br>";
        echo "OS : ".$deviceos."<br>";
        
        
        echo "dd"; // dd is written 
        $dd = new DeviceDetector($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        // nothing is written from here
        echo "dd"; 
        print_r($dd);

echo "dd";
$result = $dd->parse();

print_r($result);
}elseif($devicetype ==2){
    echo "PC";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "IP address : ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
} 

?>
```

Comment: You may need a old version check https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector/releases to find a version that suits your environment

Comment: yes I tried older version and it worked thx!!